# Need to make redux - saga call every 2 second

Tags: redux-saga

I need to make a redux-saga call every 2 seconds. How to implement it with such a code:

```
export function* getMyMeetings(action:any) {
    let {auth_uid} = action;
    const  meetings  = yield call(
          getData,
        'get',
        `api/notes/by-user/${auth_uid}`
      );
      yield put(putMeetings(meetings));
}
```

I know that I have to do this with `delay` but I can't understand how to do it. Could someone help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
export function* getMyMeetings(action:any) {
    let {auth_uid} = action;
    const  meetings  = yield call(
          getData,
        'get',
        `api/notes/by-user/${auth_uid}`
      );
      yield put(putMeetings(meetings));

      yield delay(2000); // 2 seconds sleep
      yield call(getMyMeetings, actions); // Recursive function call, first parameter is the Saga to call, the others parameters are the ones binding to this Saga function
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not clear for me what I have to put in 'actions' when we are making recursive call?

Comment: getMyMeetings is used 2 times in the code I gave you, the 2nd use of getMyMeetings makes a recursive function without any end